# Each natural projection for a basis has norm at least 1.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, schauder-basis

How to prove each natural projection for a basis has norm at least 1 ?
Also, i want to prove

"Let $(x_n)$ be a basis for a Banach space $B,$ define a new norm for the
space by $\||x\|| = \sup_n \|P_n x\|,$ and let B' be the same vector
space with the new norm. Then $(x_n)$ is a monotone basis for $B'$ i.e. i want to prove that $\sup_n \||P_n\||=1.$"

I move as following: $$\||{P_n x}\|| = \displaystyle \sup_m \|P_m P_n x\| = \displaystyle \sup \{P_1 x, P_2 x, ..., P_n x\}= \displaystyle \sup_{1 \leq m \leq n} \|P_m x\| \leq  \||{x}\||.$$
So, $\sup_n \||P_n\|| \leq 1$. I have the same problem how to prove $\sup_n\||P_n\|| \geq 1.$

Note that the two norms are equivalent $\|.\| \leq \||.\|| \leq \sup_n \|P_n\| \|.\|.$

Comment: For the first question, you only need to find one vector $x \ne 0$ such that $\|P_n x\| \ge \|x\|$.

Comment: Can you show me more?

Comment: Try $x = x_1$, the first element of the basis.

Comment: Of course, $\|P_n x_1\| = \|x_1\|$ for any n ?!

Comment: Since $P_n x_1 = x_1$, I don't see the difficulty.